# The method X in the type X is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java, generics

I am getting the following error when trying to call a method of a generic class with int argument.

`The method insertAfter(T) in the type CDLList<T>.Writer is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

The Generic class code is

```
public class CDLList<T> {
public Element Head;
static int count;
public CDLList(T v)
{
    Head = new Element(v);
}
public class Element 
{
    public T data;
    public Element next;
    public Element prev;

    Element(T v)
    {
        data = v;
        prev=null;
        next=null;
        count++;
    }
    public T value() 
    {
        return data;
    }
}
public Element head() 
{
    return Head;
}
public Cursor reader(Element from) 
{
    Cursor CurrCursor=new Cursor(from);
    return CurrCursor;
}
public class Cursor 
{
    public Element current;
    Cursor(Element v)
    {
        current=v;
    }
    public Element current() 
    {
        T temp;
        temp = current.value();
        System.out.println(temp);
        return current;
    }
    public void previous() 
    {
        current = current.prev;
    }
    public void next()
    {
        current = current.next;
    }
    public Writer writer()
    {
        Writer nwriter = new Writer( current);

        return nwriter;

    }
}



public class Writer
{
    public Element current;
    Writer(Element temp)
    {
        current=temp;
    }
    public boolean delete()
    {
        Element Td1,Td2;
        Td1 = current.prev;
        Td2 = current.next;
        current=null;
        Td1.next = Td2;
        Td2.prev = Td1;
        return true;

    }
    public boolean insertBefore(T val)
    {

        Element t = new Element(val);
        Element t2 = current.prev;
        t2.next=t;
        current.prev=t;
        t.next=current;
        t.prev=t2;      
        return true;
    }
    public boolean insertAfter(T val)
    {
        Element t = new Element(val);
        Element t1 = current.next;
        t.next=t1;
        t1.prev=t;
        current.next=t;
        t.prev=current;
        return true;

    }
}
```

}

The class implementing the generic class is

```
    public class CDLListTest<T> extends CDLList<T> implements Runnable {
Cursor cursor;

public CDLListTest(T v) {
    super(v);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            Element t1= new CDLList.Element(20); 
            -----------------------
    temp.writer().insertAfter(11); -- Getting error here
```

It works if I extend the generic class to another child generic class and extend the child generic class to a class which contains the main function.

What am I missing here? It should work since the class is generic, After googling a lot unable to find any answers

Edit: I'm sorry I was quite burned out yesterday when I was posting this question, my apologies. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Edit2: Fixed it `public class CDLListTest<T> extends CDLList<T>` should have been `public class CDLListTest<T> extends CDLList`

Comment: Please post the relevant code; you don't have any `insertAfter` defined anywhere. Most likely, you have it accepting a `T`, but then, just like the error says, you're trying to pass an `int` to it.

Comment: Java primitives are not treated as objects.

Comment: The number `11` is not of type `T` for all `T`. *Of course* it's going to give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've written a method called `insertAfter(T value)` (which you haven't shown us).  Now, you're referring to it when you're dealing with a `CDLListTest<T>` - in which `T` could be any class or interface at all.  Therefore, when you call `insertAfter`, the value you pass it must be a `T`.  But you're passing it an `int` instead of a `T`.

Either change your call to `insertAfter` to pass a `T`, or change the signature of the `insertAfter` method so that its parameter is of type `int`.